# How can I set one key on keyboard for multiple keys through AutoHotKey?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I need to press my end key, to register space+s at the same time.

From what I have heard, the code is somewhat like

```
End ::send space,s

Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to mess anything up so I am not executing it already. What I want is for the script to start pressing "Space+S" at the same time, when I press "End" and I want a key combination, let's say "9+0" to be pressed at the same time, to end the script in its track at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

**This script will keep typing `{space}s` while you are holding down <kbd>End</kbd>.**

```
End::Send, {space}s
```

Simply let go of the key when you wish to stop typing.

---

There are two parts to this script.

- `End::` -  Setup a [hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) when pressing <kbd>End</kbd>
- `Send, {space}s` - [Send keyboard input](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) for <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd>

**See Also**

- [AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm)
- [Repeating or Holding Down a Key](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key)
- [List of Keys, Mouse Buttons, and Joystick Controls](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#Keyboard)